# Remove NEGOTIATE from WindowsAuthentication in IIS

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, kerberos

I have a site running in IIS 7.5 that is accessed using a DNS alias different from the actual server name. In IE 8, integrated authentication is failing, but in Firefox and Chrome everything works fine. (IE presents a credential challenge a few times, then displays a 401.1 error page.)

I have figured out that this is due to IE using Kerberos (aka "Negotiate") over NTLM, and Kerberos requires registering a Service Principal Name (using SETSPN) so that the mismatch between the DNS name and the server name is properly handled.

My web site, however, doesn't need impersonation--it is enough to have delegation. So instead of messing with SetSPN, I would just like to remove "Negotiate" from the list of WindowsAuthentication methods in IIS.

I have searched for quite some time to find out how to do this in IIS. I have played with many `appcmd` commands--but I just can't find online examples, or figure out how by reading MSDN documentation or using `appcmd /?` to make `appcmd` commands apply only to a particular application within a site rather than to the entire web server. A few search-hours later over two days, and at least 3 dozen web pages visited, I am still coming up fruitless.

How in tarnation do I get this done--it seems like it should be so easy!

Answer (score 14):

Open the Configuration Editor in IIS. It comes with IIS 7.5, or you can download the [IIS administration pack](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/administration-pack) for IIS 7.0. Navigate to the scope you want to affect (server, site, or application) and then open the icon:

[image: IIS Configuration Editor].

Change the Section to `system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication`:

[image: IIS Configuration Editor - Windows Authentication]

Click on the `providers` item, and then click `Edit Items` on the right. Select the "Negotiate" item and click "Remove":

[image: IIS Configuration Editor - Windows Authentication - providers]

Close the dialog and click `Apply` in the `Actions` pane on the right.

Your problem is solved! No more Kerberos/negotiate!

**Note**: you can also click `Generate Script` in the actions pane to display the code that will make the change in either C#, javascript, or with appcmd from the command line.

For reference, here is the `appcmd` statement to do the job without using the Configuration Editor.

```
appcmd.exe set config "Virtual/path/to/application" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /-"providers.[value='Negotiate']" /commit:apphost
```